# Why am I always displayed among all time top users of any tag I open?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, user-experience

This was confusing me for a long time. If you open a tag's "all time top users" it'll display your profile at the very end. In some cases, for example in the below image - it's pretty clear that I'm not one of the top users (because of the huge difference in number of votes):

> [image]

---

But in some cases, it's not. For example, In the below image, I have to actually count 20 users from top to figure out if I'm actually one of the all time top contributors or not:

> [image]

Why this confusing UI? Isn't the current users profile supposed to have some visual difference and information along, "This is how far you're from becoming one" or something like that? If not, why is it even there?

Comment: I guess displaying an explicit rank/position would solve the problem.

Comment: It is explicitly showing your *your score* relative to everyone else. Some people care about this to track progress.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but it's not clear if i'm on the list or not...

Comment: @TJ: Open the URL in an anonymous browser session? Tags with so few contributors in 30 days should be relatively rare, I'd say.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think you understand. Both the screenshots have 21 contributors, the screenshots displays the end of list where I'm. My question is, how do I know If I'm actually on the list, ie on 20th position, or not, ie on 21st position -  without counting 20 users from the top? The answer below shows better UX implemented somewhere else on SO.

Comment: @TJ: but one of the screenshots has enough *recent top contributors* in the last 30 days column that you can see that you are outside of the top 20.

Comment: @TJ: In other words, I've always glanced over to that column to see if I am in or out of the top 20 in ambiguous cases. It is rare for me to care about a tag where I'm both outside the recent *and* the all time ranks, or where there have been too few contributors in the past 30 days to even fill up all 20 slots.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is totally not true, and sounds like a poor excuse to not fix bad UX.  see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/backbone.js/topusers,  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/requirejs/topusers, http://stackoverflow.com/tags/amd/topusers I don't follow the high "rush" tags cause I don't like the race for rep. This leaves poor UX for me and all other users following low profile tags. There should be a visual indicator like different background color, or atleast a horizontal line...

Comment: @TJ: I didn't say it couldn't be fixed, but it certainly lowers the priority for me over other things I'd like to see fixed more urgently (like the [search on mobile web being broken when keyboard shortcuts are enabled on a site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286345/mobile-search-made-impossible-with-keyboard-shortcuts-enabled), or [not hiding moderator flags when a redaction is pending on a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278239/active-redaction-approval-flags-hide-other-flags). :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thiught status-by-design gets forgotten forever? maybe not...

Comment: @TJ: I've removed the status again, it was a bit premature perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

I'm kinda surprised that the review states pages (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats)) get it right where the tag stats don't

[image]

Comment: That does make it hard for you to see where you are in the ranking, especially since the tag ranking uses 'human' numbers (rounded to the nearest .1 thousand).

Comment: @MartijnPieters This can be easily improved by hiding this if the user is actually on the list, or displaying both. But how it is implemented in tags makes no sense to me...

Comment: Keeping the entry where it is and simply adding a 'spacer' with a top and bottom jagged line would clearly indicate "and then a lot of users between the top 20 and you", in my opinion.